Breeze store method from RegisteredUserController not called but registration works
So this is very weird.
I have laravel 11 / Breeze.
In the breeze registration form, the post action is :
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/register">

On routes/auth.php I have :
Route::post('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store']);
But when I update the store method in this controller, nothing happens. Even if I add an exit() the registration process still works.
Even if I rename the RegisteredUserController.php it works...
Any clue? (yes, I did php artisan cache:clear)

OK, so the answer is that in my web.php I had :
require DIR.'/auth.php';
Auth::routes();
I had to remove Auth::routes(); It does not also add default route (like lhe previous require did) but seems also use default controller when it can t find the auth controller located in app/http/controllers/auth...
It is strange because it was what was written after installing Breeze.

OK, so the answer is that in my web.php I had :
require DIR.'/auth.php';
Auth::routes();
I had to remove Auth::routes(); It does not also add default route (like lhe previous require did) but seems also use default controller when it can t find the auth controller located in app/http/controllers/auth...
It is strange because it was what was written after installing Breeze.
